# Почему начинает тормозить таймер?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Через несколько циклов начинает тормозить таймер , в чем может быть причина?
Изначально делаю чтоб через определенный промежуток времени проявлялись картинки то в одном то в другом ряде, но через несколько циклов таймер сбивается. В чем может быть причина ?

Вот код :

```js
    var fn = function() {
      function animation_zone() {
        tgl++;
        if (tgl == 1) {
          $("div").fadeOut("0", function() {
            $("div").fadeOut("1000", function() {
              $("div").fadeIn("1000");
            });
          });
          $("div").fadeOut("1000", function() {
            $("div").fadeIn("1000");
            setTimeout(function() {
              $("div").fadeIn("1000", function() {})
            }, 7000)
          });

        }
        if (tgl == 2) {
          $("div").stop().fadeOut("0", function() {
            $("div").fadeOut("1000", function() {
              $("div").fadeIn("1000");
            });
          });
          $("div").fadeOut("1000", function() {
            $("div").fadeIn("1000");
          });
          setTimeout(function() {
            $("div").fadeIn("1000");
          }, 7000)
          tgl = 0;
        }
      }
      animation_zone();
      setTimeout(arguments.callee, 14300);
    }


    setTimeout(fn, 14300);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть много факторов, из-за которых может быть значительная погрешность на миллисекунды, которая со временем может стать заметной. Например, ситуации ниже могут значительно повлиять:

> **Реальная частота срабатывания**
>
> В ряде ситуаций таймер будет срабатывать реже, чем обычно. Задержка
>   между вызовами setInterval(..., 4) может быть не 4 мс, а 30 мс или
>   даже 1000 мс.
>
> - Большинство браузеров (десктопных в первую очередь) продолжают
>     выполнять setTimeout/setInterval, даже если вкладка неактивна.
> - При этом ряд из них (Chrome, FF, IE10) снижают минимальную частоту
>     таймера, до 1 раза в секунду. Получается, что в «фоновой» вкладке
>     будет срабатывать таймер, но редко.
> - При работе от батареи, в ноутбуке – браузеры тоже могут снижать
>     частоту, чтобы реже выполнять код и экономить заряд батареи. Особенно
>     этим известен IE. Снижение может достигать нескольких раз, в
>     зависимости от настроек.
> - При слишком большой загрузке процессора JavaScript может не успевать
>     обрабатывать таймеры вовремя. При этом некоторые запуски setInterval
>     будут пропущены.

Изучите подробнее тему использования таймеров и задержек срабатывания.
Детали по ссылке: [setTimeout и setInterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)